# sources.jar doesn't work with obfuscated AAR library

Tags: maven, gradle, proguard, aar, android-r8

I'm trying to publish sources.jar for closed-source AAR, but android studio doesn't pick it up to highlight API.

As i understand it should be possible, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

The library's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

apply from: 'my-maven-publish.gradle'

android {
...
    buildTypes {
        def buildChecksumString = "\"" + rootProject.ext.buildSha + "\""
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'self-proguard-rules.pro'

            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_CHECKSUM", buildChecksumString
            resValue "string", "mylib_version", version
        }
    }
...
}
```

The included 'my-maven-publish.gradle':

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'signing'

...
task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier "sources"
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
    include("**/SDK.java",
            "**/SDKListener.java") // and some other public classes
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                ...

                artifact(sourceJar)

                pom {
                  ...
                }
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

The proguard config file is keeping these public classes and looks like:

```
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, Annotation, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod, PermittedSubclasses

# Preserve all native method names and the names of their classes.
-keepclasseswithmembernames, includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}
...
-keep, includedescriptorclasses class com.my.library.SDK { *; }
-keep interface com.my.library.SDKListener { *; }
# etc. for some other public classes
...
```

*SDK.java* contains only public static methods and few inner static classes. *SDK class* is actually acting like a proxy and all its methods call *SDKInternal class'* methods (which contains private things).

I see that Android Studio downloads xxx-sources.jar and that's it. API is not highlighted with docs and all i got is decompiled class on Cmd + click.

Can you please tell me what the error is?

PS.

I am using Java and gradle files are in Groovy.

Gradle is 7.1.1

AGP is 4.1.0

Code is obfuscated with R8.

Comment: Hi @ivan-morgillo,  I read your articles and found out that you have already struggled with [a similar problem](https://www.ivanmorgillo.com/2016/03/18/android-library-aar-and-javadoc/) (by the way, you seem to be the only one who wrote about it at all). I tried the recommendations from your article, but I can't find the problem in my code.  could you give me some tips, please?